# Filtering master and detail dataset

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I'd like to implement a filter on master dataset (TADODataset) based on detail values. For example, there are customers (master dataset) and their orders (detail dataset). I'd like to filter customers with specific order type. In other words, master dataset should display only those customers who have orders with specific type.

Is it possible with master-detail relationship? How can it be implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting detail params on the Master.AfterScroll event instead of relying on the usual Master->Detail link between datasets works fine.  However, depending on what you're actually trying to do, you might do better with MDD, i.e. Orders->Customer(detail)->Orders(detail).

Comment: Could you please be more specific on this MDD thing? How can I filter customers who have orders of specific type with it?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but if you try and filter the master based on detail values, you'll likely end up with something like a dog chasing its own tail. [cont]

Comment: Instead, I'd suggest you add a another Orders dataset with "select * from Orders where ..." specifying what kind of order type you're interested in.  Then, using the Object Inspector, set a m>-d relationship between that Orders and your Customers, so your Customers are those which have Orders of the specified type.  Then, adjust the m->d between the existing Customers dataset and the existing Orders one so that that Orders shows all (?) Orders for a given customer.  If that's what you are wanting, I'll write it up as an answer, otherwise maybe it'll help you define what you actually do want.

Comment: Yes, that's almost what I want. However, there could be many Orders of the specified type. If I select one of them, then not all Customers would be displayed, but only those who have that specific Order. I need to display all Customers who have Orders of specified type (like if I select multiple Orders in new master dataset).

Comment: Well, what I described would only show the customers one at a time.  To do what you describe, instead of what I suggested, I'd try modifying the SQL for your Customer table so that it says something like SELECT C.* FROM Customer C  JOIN ORDERS O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID WHERE O.OrderType = (whatever).